# Providing class to row for drupal panel doesn't work

Tags: class, drupal, panel

I gave class to row, column and canvas for drupal minipanel but when I see the output in browser using inspect element, class for row and column doesn't appear whereas class for canvas appear. I am trying to get solution since last 2 days for this but its not working, I tried changing the permissions for ctools module. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I din't wrote any code for this. I created minipanel and added custom content, then I clicked on show layout design and gave class to row but the class doesn't appear on browser.

Comment: I was trying with panels and found something. When I create 2 rows in 1 column then class is getting rendered.